# Getting values from variables - bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to write a bash script to print values of the 3 variables. Keep getting errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
INPUT1=/tmp/dir1
INPUT2=/tmp/dir2
INPUT3=/tmp/dir3

for i in 1 2 3
do 
echo $(INPUT$i)
done
```

When I run this script, tho output is:

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/tmp/dir1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash doesn't support that kind of syntax directly. You could use 'eval', however with modern versions of 'bash' the cleanest way imho is via an array

```
input=( "/tmp/dir1" "/tmp/dir2" "/tmp/dir3" )

for i in {0,1,2}; do echo "${input[i]}"; done
```

(note that bash arrays are zero-indexed); or to list all elements you can use

```
for i in "${input[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree that using an array as shown in other answers is a better way to solve the real task of the OP.
But these answers do not directly answer the question as stated, so I'll do that:

Here is how you can do that with `eval` to access the variables, following closely the way the OP gave as his code:

```
INPUT1=/tmp/dir1
INPUT2=/tmp/dir2
INPUT3=/tmp/dir3

for i in {1..3} ; do
    eval "echo \$INPUT$i"
done
```

Output:

```
/tmp/dir1
/tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir3
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define `INPUT` variable as an array:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

INPUT[1]=/tmp/dir1
INPUT[2]=/tmp/dir2
INPUT[3]=/tmp/dir3

for i in "${INPUT[@]}"
do 
echo $i     #or $INPUT[$i]
done
```

See also: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop-array/

Comment: This doesnt work. "for i in "${INPUT[@]}"". I get the following error :  syntax error: operand expected (error token is ..

Comment: @Ubuntuser Are you use bash shell as you tagged your question? Or how do you run the script?

Comment: Yes its bash in Ubuntu 13.04.  
`for i in {0,1,2};`  works for me

Comment: @Ubuntuser How do you run the script?

Comment: ./script-name.sh is what I use.

Comment: @Ubuntuser Well, I don't know what to say... Of course you have a problem with your bash. See [this immage](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W2uBV.png).

Answer (score 0):

[`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html) actually supports something pretty close to what you first tried.

```
INPUT1=/tmp/dir1
INPUT2=/tmp/dir2
INPUT3=/tmp/dir3

for s in INPUT{1..3}; do
    echo ${!s}
done
```

This works because:

- `INPUT{1..3}` expands to `INPUT1 INPUT2 INPUT3`. (It's equivalent to `INPUT{1,2,3}`.)
- Where `$s` is the expansion of `s`, `${!s}` is the expansion *of the expansion* of `s`.

  For example, in the first iteration of the loop, if `$s` appeared it would be expanded to `INPUT1`. If `$INPUT1` appeared it would be expanded to `/tmp/dir1`. Thus `${!s}` is expanded to `/tmp/dir1`.

  This kind of [parameter expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is called *indirect expansion*. In this situation and many like it, the built-in `!` syntax achieves this more compactly and elegantly than `eval`.

  <sup>**For more information, see [Is it possible to build variable names from other variables in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963494/is-it-possible-to-build-variable-names-from-other-variables-in-bash) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).**</sup>

Some caveats (which also apply to some of the other answers that have been posted):

- If any values of `INPUTn` may contain [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)<sup>**1**</sup> (like spaces<sup>**2**</sup>, [tabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters), or [newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)) or [constructions with special characters that would be expanded](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) (such as `$varname`), [quoting](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) should be used.

  Single quotes for the assignment are best if you want to prevent all expansion there:
  `INPUT1=/tmp/dir1` → `INPUT1='/tmp/dir with   spaces'`

  <sup>(Only a `'` quote character is treated specially, as it will act as the closing quote mark.)</sup>

  But use double quotes to still allow the variable to be expanded:
  `echo ${!s}` → `echo "${!s}"`

  <sup>(This works even if the value after expansion contains a `$`. The expanded contents are not expanded again.

  For example, `BAZ=QUUX FOO='BAR   $BAZ'; echo "$FOO"` prints `BAR   $BAZ`, *not* `BAR   QUUX`.)</sup>
- If any of `INPUTn` might take on a value that `echo` would interpret as an [option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option) instead of text to print, replace `echo` with `printf '%s\n'`.<sup>**3**</sup>

  Currently this is `-` followed by one more `e`, `E`, or `n`. But you should probably consider anything starting with `-` as dangerous in case future bash versions add new options.

---

Although, in terms of syntax, indirect expansion as presented above is nearly as simple as doing it with an array, **you still may wish to use an array** because:

- It may better reflect the underlying meaning of the problem you're trying to solve.
- You might have use for other features of arrays in solving this problem.

Perhaps you intended `/tmp/dir1`, `/tmp/dir2`, and `/tmp/dir3` as opaque examples that may be replaced by anything.

But if you really want to make an array of those specific values, I recommend:

```
input=(/tmp/dir{1..3})
```

Similarly, if your goal is just to loop through `/tmp/dir1`, `/tmp/dir2`, and `/tmp/dir3` and perform some action with each, then **you don't need to store them in any kind of variable**:

```
for s in /tmp/dir{1..3}; do
    echo $s
done
```

If the values of `s` will contain whitespace or special characters (see above), quote them, but leave the `{...}` range unquoted by separately quoting the text to the left and right of it--it won't be expanded if quoted, even in double quotes.

```
for s in '/tmp/dir '{1..3}' with  spaces'; do
    echo "$s"
done
```

That prints:

```
/tmp/dir 1 with  spaces
/tmp/dir 2 with  spaces
/tmp/dir 3 with  spaces
```

And if your goal is really just to print `/tmp/dir1`, `/tmp/dir2`, and `/tmp/dir3`, each on its own line, then this single command<sup>**3**</sup> is sufficient:

```
printf '%s\n' /tmp/dir{1..3}
```

---

<sup>**1**: The shell [splits text into words](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) on whitespace or, if the `IFS` variable is defined, on the field separators it specifies. But you usually don't have to worry about `IFS` unless you've set it yourself.</sup>

<sup>**2**: `echo hello world` actually does work: it prints `hello world`, just like `echo 'hello world'`. This is because `echo` prints a single space between each echoed [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments). However, `echo hello   world` is not equivalent to `echo 'hello   world'`: the former still prints `hello world` while latter prints `hello   world`.</sup>

<sup>**3**: For more information on `bash`'s `printf` builtin, see the [output of `help printf`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8373180/) or [this section of the Bash manual](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins). `printf` is also [an executable that can be called from other shells](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/printf.1.html) (and in that capacity [is standardized](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/printf.1posix.html)).</sup>