# How to check whether a file is in current directory or its subdirectories?

Tags: bash, scripts

I use find to search for files in a directory or its subdirectories.
`find  . -iname '*.csv'`, and it gives me the following output

```
./2012/t1.csv
./2012/t2.csv
./2013/t1.csv
```

Now, I want to check in a script whether the file `t1.csv` is in the current folder or in one of the subdirectories. If it's in a subdirectory, my script should descend to that directory.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

To check only for `t1.csv`, you can use:

```
find . -name 't1.csv'
```

Now, to go in the first directory where `t1.csv` file is found, you can use:

```
cd $(dirname $(find . -name 't1.csv' 2>/dev/null | head -1)  2>/dev/null)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But i am actually trying to compress all csv files into the same folder by going inside each folder.

Comment: @Ubuntuser And where you said something about this in your question? If you don't see clear, the question is: *how to check whether a file is in current directory or subdirectory* and *if its in a subdirectory, my script should descend to that directory*

Comment: @Ubuntuser If you have another question, please use [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: I have asked the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649393/find-and-gzip-files-in-subdirectories. See if you can answer it there :)

Comment: Also it will not work. `dirname ./2012/t1.csv` will give you ./2012. you cannot cd into that folder

Comment: @Ubuntuser It's working like a charm. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qKW1i.png). [I told you](http://askubuntu.com/questions/337394/getting-values-from-variables-bash-script#comment435891_337408) that you may have a problem with your bash/terminal :) ...Maybe some broken settings.

Comment: Check this script please `#!/bin/bash`

`for file in `find . -iname *.csv``
`do`
`echo $file`
 `if [[ ! -f $file ]];then`
        `echo "Not in this directory, changing directory" `pwd``
        `cd $(dirname $file)`

`fi`
`done` This doesnt change directory

Comment: If you mean that directory won't be changed /after/ script execution, this is right. The script is runing in a subshell, and cannot change the parent shell working directory. Replace pwd with comand you want to run inside new directory or source script this way: http://askubuntu.com/questions/84279/how-to-change-directory-using-script

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ -f t1.csv ]
then
    echo "File is in target dir"
else
    cd `dirname $(find . -iname 't1.csv')`
    pwd
fi
```

Comment: I dont think it helps. you see, find command gives the path. So if i do an if statement on the file, it will always find it. I need to check if this file is present in the current directory.

Comment: Yes it does: all you need to do extra is check if it has more than 1 backslash ;) (./111/111 versus ./1111)

Comment: Rinzewind, please tell me more about why more then 1 backslash is needed?

Comment: No, find do not test where the command `[ -f t1.csv ]` does, as can be seen in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty comprehensive discussion on it here:

- [How to use "grep" command to find text including subdirectories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55325/how-to-use-grep-command-to-find-text-including-subdirectories)

... see also the grep man pages of course

Not sure about the 2nd part of your question though, but hope that sends you in the right direction.